# Changing map type shows blank screen in Android Studio with Kotlin

Tags: android, api, kotlin, google-maps

Whenever the menu button is clicked the map should change to TERRAIN instead it shows blank screen :(

```
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(item.itemId == R.id.miChangeMap) {
            mMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyVgL.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmRxa.png)

Maybe the syntax is wrong, I have tried searching for the solution but all in vain
Are there any permissions or dependencies I should implement?

Comment: Make sure that the Google Maps API key you are using is authorized to use the TERRAIN map type.

Comment: The code seems OK. You need to see Map on your Android app, so make sure all requirement of Google Map API for your Android application achieved.